# Allow iOS In-app purchases to be bought only in the app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

Depending on certain parameters, we want to offer our users a different subscription in app product to be bought in our app. This basically works very well as our app can control which of the available in app products will be shown to the user. However on the app store page of our app the user can freely choose to subscripe to whatever in app product he wants. Is there any way to disable this (so that users can only buy through our app and not in the app store)? If not, how else could we handle this scenario?

Comment: Where can you purchase subscription in AppStore page app ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For more clarity: I published to Subscription offers to the App Store. Depending on certain cirsumstances (e.g. black friday) I show either the cheaper or the normal offer to the user. In the app, I can decide which subscription to show. However in the App Store (in the manage Subscription section) the user is free to subscripe to whichever subscription he wants. Is there any way to disable this in the app store?